# Restrict the length of a match

Tags: c#, regex

What would this C# regex look like?

- At least one (1) character in length
- Up to seven (7) characters in length
- Numeric characters

I have this, but I needs to check for 1-7 digits:

```
var chequeNumRX = new Regex("^[0-9]+$");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regular expressions, you can use the [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) operator `{min,max}`.

```
var chequeNumRX = new Regex(@"^\d{1,7}$");
```

The above regex would match `\d` a minimum of 1 time and a maximum of 7 times.

Note that `\d` is a shorthand character class equivalent to `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the range in after your list of charaters:

`{1,7}` : allows 1 - 7 charaters

e.g

```
^[0-9]{1,7}$
```